# How to enable zoom in and out using mouse scroll in embedded map in html?

Tags: html, css

I have added an embedded map in a html page. code for it is as bellow

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=+&amp;q=anaveer+info+media&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=anaveer+info+media&amp;hnear=Ahmedabad,+Gujarat&amp;ll=23.036523,72.560641&amp;spn=0.011078,0.021136&amp;t=m&amp;z=19&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=8621019355742313992&amp;output=embed" align="middle"></iframe><br />
```

I have one problem that this map is not getting zoom in and out on mouse scroll. can any one have solution for that

Comment: Try clicking with left mouse button anywhere on the map and then use your mouse scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Static Maps API which if I'm not mistaken does not have the zoom functionality you seek. If you want to enable mouse zoom, you should use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)